# Java string stop the escape character action

Tags: java, escaping, stringbuilder

My question is suppose I have a string and a string builder:

```
String sample = "Ran\"dom";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
```

On appending the sample string to the StringBuilder and printing the String builder, it returns "HelloRan"dom"

Here the purpose of "\" in sample would be to escape the " character. But, I do not want that action to happen. I want the output of sb after appending sample to be "HelloRan\"dom". How do I do that.

Comment: Try `"Ran\\\"dom"`, it will escape both the backslash and the double quote.

Comment: You would need to *escape* the `\\` with another `\\` character: `String sample = "Ran\\"dom";`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the whole "\"" with another "\".
Try,

```
String sample = "Ran\\\"dom";
```

You can learn more about escape characters from https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, try:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
... 
String sample = "Ran\"dom";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");

System.out.println(sb+StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(sample));
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```